# Why doesn't the first do while loop end when the while condition is met?

Tags: java, do-while

The primary problem I'm having is at the first do while loop which I can't exit the program when the condition is met.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    final double milkPrice = 2;
    final double sodaPrice = 2.25;
    final double cbarPrice = 1.25;
    final double gbearsPrice = 1.50;
    final double chipsPrice = 1;
    double usersMoney = 0;
    double moneyLeft = 0;
    double tempMoneyLeft = 0;
    int milkQnty = 5;
    int sodaQnty = 4;
    int cbarQnty = 5;
    int gbearsQnty = 6;
    int chipsQnty = 6;
    char usersSelection;

    do{
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Vending Machine!");
        System.out.println("I sense that your are hungry... This is what I have to offer:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\tItem" + "\t\tPrice" + "\t\tQuantity");
        System.out.println("\tMilk" + "\t\t$2.00" + "\t\t" + milkQnty);
        System.out.println("\tSoda" + "\t\t$2.25" + "\t\t" + sodaQnty);
        System.out.println("\tCandy Bar" + "\t$1.25" + "\t\t" + cbarQnty);
        System.out.println("\tGummy Bears" + "\t$1.50" + "\t\t" + gbearsQnty);
        System.out.println("\tChips" + "\t\t$1.00" + "\t\t" + chipsQnty);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please enter how much money you have to spend (enter -1 to shut down): ");
        usersMoney = scan.nextDouble();
```

Specifically this is where I'm having the problem, I think. It just keeps going to the next statement which happens to be the nested do-while loop.

```
            do {
                System.out.print("Please make a selection:" + 
                        "\nA-Milk, B-Soda, C-Candy Bar, D-Gummy Bears, E-Chips, X-Exit: ");
                usersSelection = scan.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

                switch (usersSelection) {
                case 'A':
                    tempMoneyLeft = usersMoney - milkPrice;
                    moneyLeft = tempMoneyLeft - moneyLeft;
                    System.out.println("You have bought Milk for " + milkPrice + ". You still have " +
                            moneyLeft + " left.");
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case 'B':
                    tempMoneyLeft = usersMoney - sodaPrice;
                    moneyLeft = tempMoneyLeft - moneyLeft;
                    System.out.println("You have bought Soda for " + sodaPrice + ". You still have " +
                            moneyLeft + " left.");
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case 'C':
                    tempMoneyLeft = usersMoney - cbarPrice;
                    moneyLeft = tempMoneyLeft - moneyLeft;
                    System.out.println("You have bought Candy Bar for " + cbarPrice + ". You still have " +
                            moneyLeft + " left.");
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case 'D':
                    tempMoneyLeft = usersMoney - gbearsPrice;
                    moneyLeft = tempMoneyLeft - moneyLeft;
                    System.out.println("You have bought Gummy Bears for " + gbearsPrice + ". You still have " +
                            moneyLeft + " left.");
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case 'E':
                    tempMoneyLeft = usersMoney - chipsPrice;
                    moneyLeft = tempMoneyLeft - moneyLeft;
                    System.out.println("You have bought Chips for " + chipsPrice + ". You still have " +
                            moneyLeft + " left.");
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case 'X':
                    System.out.println("Thank you for your purchases: Your change is " + moneyLeft);
                    break;
                }
                if(!(usersSelection == 'A' || usersSelection == 'B' || usersSelection == 'C' || usersSelection == 'D'
                        || usersSelection == 'E' || usersSelection == 'X')) {
                    System.out.print("Invalid Entry!\t");
                }
            } while (usersSelection != 'X');

        } while (usersMoney != -1);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Thank you for your business!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do-while loops exit when their loop condition is _not_ met.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom so what solution could I possibly use?

Comment: The condition is *only* checked before each time the loop body runs (for most loops) or after each time it runs (for do-while loops).

Comment: Entering -1 and x (as supposed reading your code) exited properly.

Comment: When -1 is entered then it goes on to prompt the user pick their selection and if they enter x then it exits the whole program completely but that only happens when both -1 and x are entered. I want to be able to exit the program if the user enters -1

Comment: `while(usersMoney != -1)` Ha ha.. funny condition :)

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading your question, I finally understood what you really want.

Actually, if you want to exit when the condition of the first loop *is not met*, then since you have nested loops, you must change the condition of the inner.

Also, you need to change the inner loop from a do..while to a simple while.

So your code would look like this :

```
char usersSelection = ' ';

do {
    usersMoney = scan.nextDouble();
    while(usersMoney != -1 && usersSelection != 'X')//will be automatically skipped if -1 is entered
    {
        System.out.print("Please make a selection:"
                + "\nA-Milk, B-Soda, C-Candy Bar, D-Gummy Bears, E-Chips, X-Exit: ");
        usersSelection = scan.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        //switch statement here
    }

} while (usersMoney != -1);
```

Using this algorithm will exit directly if you enter -1.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the reason I have nested do while loops is because I want to keep prompting the user to make another selection unless the user decides to exit

Comment: @Jay my example still contains nested loops and will meet your requirement. The only difference is that I changed the do..while to a while. Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the while condition to `usersMoney == -1` it should work properly. As you have written, you're asking the user to input -1 to exit, although in your condition you're telling "only if usersMoney is different than -1". 
I would also recommend using `default` inside the `switch` instead of the lengthy `if`. Simply replacing it by: 
`default: System.out.print("Invalid Entry!\t");`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a nested loop. When condition for the inner loop is met, the one for the first might not have, so it will continue to run and it will never exit when user has -1 unless he also chooses 'X'.

Try this

```
do {
    System.out.print("Please make a selection:" + 
            "\nA-Milk, B-Soda, C-Candy Bar, D-Gummy Bears, E-Chips, X-Exit: ");
    usersSelection = scan.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    switch (usersSelection) {
    case 'A':
        tempMoneyLeft = usersMoney - milkPrice;
        moneyLeft = tempMoneyLeft - moneyLeft;
        System.out.println("You have bought Milk for " + milkPrice + ". You still have " +
                moneyLeft + " left.");
        System.out.println();
        break;

    case 'B':
        tempMoneyLeft = usersMoney - sodaPrice;
        moneyLeft = tempMoneyLeft - moneyLeft;
        System.out.println("You have bought Soda for " + sodaPrice + ". You still have " +
                moneyLeft + " left.");
        System.out.println();
        break;

    case 'C':
        tempMoneyLeft = usersMoney - cbarPrice;
        moneyLeft = tempMoneyLeft - moneyLeft;
        System.out.println("You have bought Candy Bar for " + cbarPrice + ". You still have " +
                moneyLeft + " left.");
        System.out.println();
        break;

    case 'D':
        tempMoneyLeft = usersMoney - gbearsPrice;
        moneyLeft = tempMoneyLeft - moneyLeft;
        System.out.println("You have bought Gummy Bears for " + gbearsPrice + ". You still have " +
                moneyLeft + " left.");
        System.out.println();
        break;

    case 'E':
        tempMoneyLeft = usersMoney - chipsPrice;
        moneyLeft = tempMoneyLeft - moneyLeft;
        System.out.println("You have bought Chips for " + chipsPrice + ". You still have " +
                moneyLeft + " left.");
        System.out.println();
        break;

    case 'X':
        System.out.println("Thank you for your purchases: Your change is " + moneyLeft);
        break;
    }
    if(!(usersSelection == 'A' || usersSelection == 'B' || usersSelection == 'C' || usersSelection == 'D'
            || usersSelection == 'E' || usersSelection == 'X')) {
        System.out.print("Invalid Entry!\t");
    }
    if(usersMoney < 0) break;

} while (usersSelection != 'X');

System.out.println();
System.out.print("Thank you for your business!");
```

}